# Connecting to SQL Server database mdf file error

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

When I deploy my Windows application written in C#, I get an error:

> this  Database  already exists

Here is my code :

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|direct.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"); app.config :  <add name="DIRECTPERFERMANCE.Properties.Settings.directConnectionString"

connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\direct.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Does the database, in fact, already exist?

Comment: yes but its not connected to sql because i wanna to deploye it at client machine